# $http.get return root page angular & laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, routes

I have this angular code

```
var loginApp = angular.module('login', []);

loginApp.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.email = "";

    $scope.doLogin = function()
    {
        if($scope.password.trim() != "" && this.isEmailValid())
        {
            $http.get('/AuthLogin')
                .success(function(response)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .error(function(error) 
                {
                    alert(error);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

and here is the laravel routes.php:

```
<?php
Route::get('/AuthLogin', function()
{
    return 'success';
});

App::missing(function($exception)
{
    Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');      // for variables and all things Blade
    Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');     // for escaped data
    return View::make('index');
});

?>
```

The problem is that I am getting the main root `/` page as a response of the `$http.get` instead of "success". Why?

Thanks!

Comment: try to add slash : $http.get('//AuthLogin')

Comment: @IlyasMimouni I am getting an error: GET http://authlogin/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: ok, try directly in navigator : localhost/AutoLogin. if this not working then the probleme is in the route.

Comment: still the same. who is making the problem angular or laravel?

Comment: I think it will work in IE but not in firefox or chrome, so try the methode in post.

Comment: there is no problem in angular, but you should verify if server is configured well

Answer (score 0):

try the following method :

Run cmd.exe as an administrator 
Type "netsh winsock reset", and then press enter 
Restart PC